# kotlin-js gradle outputfile wrong

Tags: javascript, gradle, kotlin

I'm working on kotlin-js example. I used this [sample](https://github.com/alphamu/KotlinFullstackSample). When I was build frontend module(as shown in the picture below) I can't see **web** folder. But the resource files should be in **web** folder. What's wrong?

[Project Source Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3qLmQ.png)

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.2.30'

    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    }
}

group 'example'
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

apply plugin: 'kotlin2js'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-js:$kotlin_version"
    testCompile "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-test-js:$kotlin_version"
}

build.doLast {
    configurations.compile.each { File file ->
        copy {
            includeEmptyDirs = false

            from zipTree(file.absolutePath)
            into "${projectDir}/web"
            include { fileTreeElement ->
                def path = fileTreeElement.path
                path.endsWith(".js") && (path.startsWith("META-INF/resources/") || !path.startsWith("META-INF/"))
            }
        }
    }
}

compileKotlin2Js {
    kotlinOptions.outputFile = "${projectDir}/web/output.js"
    kotlinOptions.sourceMap = true
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `copy { ... }` block only sets up copying of the dependency files from the `compile` configuration, and it does not copy the resources of your project into `web`. Neither does the `compileKotlin2Js` task, which only puts the compiled Kotlin classes into that directory.

To copy the resources of the `main` source set, you can add another `copy { ... }` block, like this:

```
build.doLast {
    // ...
    copy { 
        from sourceSets.main.output.resourcesDir
        into "${projectDir}/web"
    }
}
```

And note that if you only copy the files, you may end up with stale output files left from the previous run (if a file no more exists in the source directory, its copy is not deleted from the target). Instead, consider using the default output file location for the `compileKotlin2Js` task and a [`Sync` task](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.Sync.html) to synchronize the directories, as described in [this guide](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/tutorials/javascript/getting-started-gradle/getting-started-with-gradle.html) (it does not mention the resources; add them with `from ...` as suggested above). If you need to customize the output file name, you can [use `archivesBaseName`](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/using-gradle.html#module-names) for that.